# Multiple-level Filtering in Javascript/Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array which looks like this:

```
var selection = ["14-3","19-5", "23-5", "40-8", "41-8"];
```

Now, I have two arrays: Array1 refers to first parts of the values (before hyptens) in the above array, like 19, 23, etc. Array2 contains values containing 2nd part - 5,8, etc.

```
Array1 = ["23", "40"]
Array2 = ["5", "8"]
```

I want to filter the selection array such that:

- All items where none of Array2 values match should return
- For items where any Array2 value matches, only the ones with Array1 match are returned.

In the above case, the filtered array will be as follows:

```
filteredSelection = ["14-3", "23-5", "40-8"]
```

I know how to do a simple filter using .filter() that can filter an array by another array. But in this case, I don't know to to filter this. Please help.

Comment: How does the `14-3` is included?

Comment: That's criteria 1. The second part 3 is not in Array2. All items where none of Array2 values match should return

Comment: Right, i changed it to Javascript/Jquery.

Comment: It's still just Javascript. There's no jQuery here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could exclude values of `array2` and includes values of `array1`.

```js
var selection = ["14-3","19-5", "23-5", "40-8", "41-8"],
    array1 = ["23", "40"],
    array2 = ["5", "8"],
    result = selection.filter(s => {
        const [l, r] = s.split('-');
        return !array2.includes(r) || array1.includes(l);
    });

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this-

```js
const selection = ["14-3","19-5", "23-5", "40-8", "41-8"];
const Array1 = ["23", "40"];
const Array2 = ["5", "8"];

const obj1 = Array1.reduce((acc, curr) => ({...acc, [curr]: 1}), {});
const obj2 = Array2.reduce((acc, curr) => ({...acc, [curr]: 1}), {});

const res = selection.filter(item => {
  const [left, right] = item.split('-');
  return obj1[left] || obj2[right] === undefined;
});

console.log(res);
```

Converted `Array1` and `Array2` to objects so that it is cost-effective. It would be great if you can declare the `Array1` and `Array2` as objects initially.

Comment: If you're looking for efficiency, `Set()` may be better than objects.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to use `filter` as long as you know what you are doing:

```js
const filteredSelection = selection.filter(el => {
const [first, second] = el.split('-');
return !Array2.includes(second) || Array1.includes(first);
});
```